# unbearable discrimination

Tags: adjectives

a. They spoke out against the unbearable discrimination they witnessed there.

b. They spoke out against the insufferable sexism in their workplace.

Do these imply that 'they' consider some amount of discrimination bearable and some forms of sexism tolerable?

Could they be used if for them all discrimination was unbearable and all sexism insufferable?

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not imply those conclusions.

Language is language, not logic.

An adjective can be used to classify or restrict something, but (especially intensives like *insufferable* and *intolerable*) can also be used to express an attitude or evaluation on something: they express not properties of the thing described (the discrimination or sexism) but the speaker's attitude towards it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It doesn't follow in the logical sense - the sentence only describes the discrimination they witness, and the sexism in their workplace, it makes no statement on any other kinds of discrimination and sexism. If I say, for example:

> I couldn't stand looking at him beating his wife.

it doesn't imply that I could stand looking at him doing something else, that I could stand looking at someone else beating his wife, or that I could stand looking at him beating someone else's wife. It just makes a statement about that particular situation.

And either way, trying to interpret what's essentially a rhetorical intensifier literally is moot - we *bear* the *unbearable* and *suffer* the *insufferable* all the time. Those words are there to charge the statement emotionally for the reader - it's more outrageous to read about *unbearable discrimination* than just plain *discrimination* - and very likely not to make any sort of judgment about what is and is not bearable and sufferable.